# Icon's hover won't line up

Tags: html, css

The login icon's hover feature keeps going to the left and not lining up with the icon itself.

I know it is because it is within the nav element which has a class for text, but I am completely blanking on how to fix it. I want to keep the icon in the nav element. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML and CSS

```css
.fixed-nav-bar {
         position: fixed;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
         z-index: 9999;
         width: 100%;
         height: 46px;
         background-color: #262626;
         overflow: hidden;
       }
     
       .fixed-nav-bar a {
        color: #ffffff;
        float: left;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
     
      .fixed-nav-bar a:hover {
         background-color: #ddd;
         color: black;
      }
     
      .fixed-nav-bar a.active {
          background-color: #4CAF50;
          color: white;
      }
     
   
    .material-icons {

        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 3px;
        right: 12px;
     }  
   
      .material-icons {
        text-align: right;
        color: white;
        font-size: 40;
      }
   
       .material-icons a:hover {
          background-color: #ddd;
          color: black;
        }
```

```html
<nav class="fixed-nav-bar">
        <a href="home">Home</a>
        <a href="Example">Examples</a>
        <a href="About">About</a>
        <a href="Contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="login"><i class="material-icons">&#xe851;</i></a>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `<a>` tag for the icon has the same `float: left` applied to it that the other links have (defined in `.fixed-nav-bar a`).

You can correct this by applying a `float: right` rule to the `<a>` tag for the icon with a selector that has higher **[specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)**. There's no simple selector for this, but fortunately you can make use of the **[`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type)** pseudo-selector:

```
.fixed-nav-bar a:last-of-type {
  float: right;
}
```

This can be seen working in the following example:

```css
.fixed-nav-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 46px;
  background-color: #262626;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fixed-nav-bar a {
  color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.fixed-nav-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.fixed-nav-bar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.material-icons {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 12px;
}

.material-icons {
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40;
}

.material-icons a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.fixed-nav-bar a:last-of-type {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<nav class="fixed-nav-bar">
  <a href="home">Home</a>
  <a href="Example">Examples</a>
  <a href="About">About</a>
  <a href="Contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="login"><i class="material-icons">&#xe851;</i></a>
</nav>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Aw yes! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Move `class="material-icons"` to `<a>` tag and update your css `.material-icons` with `top:0px`

**Changes:**

`<a href="login"  class="material-icons"><i>&#xe851;</i></a>`

```
    .material-icons {

        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        right: 12px;
     }
```

**Snippet:**

```css
.fixed-nav-bar {
         position: fixed;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
         z-index: 9999;
         width: 100%;
         height: 46px;
         background-color: #262626;
         overflow: hidden;
       }
     
       .fixed-nav-bar a {
        color: #ffffff;
        float: left;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
     
      .fixed-nav-bar a:hover {
         background-color: #ddd;
         color: black;
      }
     
      .fixed-nav-bar a.active {
          background-color: #4CAF50;
          color: white;
      }
     
   
    .material-icons {

        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        right: 12px;
     }  
   
      .material-icons {
        text-align: right;
        color: white;
        font-size: 40;
      }
   
       .material-icons a:hover {
          background-color: #ddd;
          color: black;
        }
```

```html
<nav class="fixed-nav-bar">
        <a href="home">Home</a>
        <a href="Example">Examples</a>
        <a href="About">About</a>
        <a href="Contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="login"  class="material-icons"><i>&#xe851;</i></a>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Insert this:**

```
a[href="login"] {
    float: right;
}
```

```css
.fixed-nav-bar {
         position: fixed;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
         z-index: 9999;
         width: 100%;
         height: 46px;
         background-color: #262626;
         overflow: hidden;
       }
     
       .fixed-nav-bar a {
        color: #ffffff;
        float: left;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
     
      .fixed-nav-bar a:hover {
         background-color: #ddd;
         color: black;
      }
     
      .fixed-nav-bar a.active {
          background-color: #4CAF50;
          color: white;
      }
     
   a[href="login"]{
    float: right;
   }
   
    .material-icons {

        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 3px;
        right: 12px;
     }  
   
      .material-icons {
        text-align: right;
        color: white;
        font-size: 40;
      }
   
       .material-icons a:hover {
          background-color: #ddd;
          color: black;
        }
```

```html
<nav class="fixed-nav-bar">
        <a href="home">Home</a>
        <a href="Example">Examples</a>
        <a href="About">About</a>
        <a href="Contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="login"><i class="material-icons">&#xe851;</i></a>
</nav>
```

**For 100% height, remove `position: absolute;`:**

```css
.fixed-nav-bar {
         position: fixed;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
         z-index: 9999;
         width: 100%;
         height: 46px;
         background-color: #262626;
         overflow: hidden;
       }
     
       .fixed-nav-bar a {
        color: #ffffff;
        float: left;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
     
      .fixed-nav-bar a:hover {
         background-color: #ddd;
         color: black;
      }
     
      .fixed-nav-bar a.active {
          background-color: #4CAF50;
          color: white;
      }
     
   a[href="login"]{
    float: right;
   }

  
      .material-icons {
        text-align: right;
        color: white;
        font-size: 40;
        cursor: pointer;

      }
   
       .material-icons a:hover {
          background-color: #ddd;
          color: black;
        }
```

```html
<nav class="fixed-nav-bar">
        <a href="home">Home</a>
        <a href="Example">Examples</a>
        <a href="About">About</a>
        <a href="Contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="login"><i class="material-icons">&#xe851;</i></a>
</nav>
```